# How to create Windows simple storage pool?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019

In Windows Server 2019, I am trying to create a simple storage pool with 6 disks using Powershell.  The total size should be about 42 TB, but it creates a pool of only 1.23 TB.  The rest is still part of the primordial pool.  Here is how the disks look before.

```
PS D:\> Get-PhysicalDisk | Where Size -eq 7681501126656

DeviceId FriendlyName               SerialNumber                             MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage          Size
-------- ------------               ------------                             --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----          ----
1        SAMSUNG MZQLB7T6HMLA-00007 3442_4730_4D80_1590_0025_3859_0000_0001. SSD       True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 6.99 TB
4        SAMSUNG MZQLB7T6HMLA-00007 3442_4730_4D80_1589_0025_3859_0000_0001. SSD       True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 6.99 TB
2        SAMSUNG MZQLB7T6HMLA-00007 3442_4730_4D80_1270_0025_3859_0000_0001. SSD       True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 6.99 TB
6        SAMSUNG MZQLB7T6HMLA-00007 3442_4730_4D80_1588_0025_3859_0000_0001. SSD       True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 6.99 TB
3        SAMSUNG MZQLB7T6HMLA-00007 3442_4730_4D80_1586_0025_3859_0000_0001. SSD       True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 6.99 TB
5        SAMSUNG MZQLB7T6HMLA-00007 3442_4730_4D80_1541_0025_3859_0000_0001. SSD       True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 6.99 TB
```

Here is the command to create the pool

```
PS D:\> $PD = (Get-PhysicalDisk | Where Size -eq 7681501126656)
PS D:\> New-StoragePool -FriendlyName NVMePool -Verbose -PhysicalDisks $PD -StorageSubSystemFriendlyName "Windows Storage*" -ResiliencySettingNameDefault Simple

FriendlyName OperationalStatus HealthStatus IsPrimordial IsReadOnly    Size AllocatedSize
------------ ----------------- ------------ ------------ ----------    ---- -------------
NVMePool     OK                Healthy      False        False      1.23 TB        1.5 GB
```

And the results

```
PS D:\> Get-StoragePool

FriendlyName OperationalStatus HealthStatus IsPrimordial IsReadOnly     Size AllocatedSize
------------ ----------------- ------------ ------------ ----------     ---- -------------
NVMePool     OK                Healthy      False        False       1.23 TB        1.5 GB
Primordial   OK                Healthy      True         False      42.79 TB       1.24 TB
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  These disks had existing partitions from a previous application.  So the storage pool was only using the first partition of each.  The solution is to wipe each disk with `diskpart clean`